# Java MySQL DELETE statement issue

Tags: java, mysql

Using:

```
String query = "DELETE FROM Candidates WHERE COD = ?";
declaratie.setInt(1, 11);
```

it works.

But, if I use this expression:

```
String query = "DELETE FROM Candidati WHERE ? = ?";
declaratie.setString(1, "COD");            
declaratie.setInt(2, 11);
```

it runs, without errors, but does nothing...

Am I using it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your second expression does nothing as the condition is "wrong": The condition is `'COD' = 11` which evaluates to `false`, because the first parameter is a string, and not `COD = 11`.

You cannot modify the query or hand in column names using prepared statements. You can only pass values which are handled as parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Your first statement is running because `?` is used for setting parameters. The second is not running because you can not set column name as parameter